# How to draw hyperbola with addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw hyperbola with `pgfplots`:

(x+1)^2/4-(y-2)^2/9=1

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This site usually works best when you present your best attempt.  It's also polite to give us a minimal working example that we can start from.

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm starting to use TikZ , so I do not show any initial work.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use (y-2)^2/9=(x+1)^2/4-1 and take the square root (plus or minus).  Note that x<-3 or x>1, so you will need four \addplots total.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in comments, you can reformulate the equation as "y = f(x)" with the problem of roots.

An alternative is to interprete it as "f(x,y)= (x+1)^2/4-(y-2)^2/9" and draw the contour "f(x,y) = 1" :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[domain=-10:10,
        contour gnuplot={labels=false,levels={1}}
    ] {(x+1)^2/4-(y-2)^2/9};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The value `domain=-10:10` determines the computed range. Since `domain y` is missing, pgfplots assumes that it should also use `-10:10`.

Note that you need to compile this by means of `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` and you need `gnuplot` installed.

Note that the approach as such works for any kind of plot program, not just `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend googling around for a tikz/pgf tutorial to learn at least the basics on your own.  You'll learn much more that way.

The most straightforward approach here is to solve for y=2±√(9*(x+1)^2/4-9) with `x < -3` or `1 < x`.  Plotting this requires four commands, and results in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]
        \addplot[domain=-10:-3] {2+sqrt(9*(x+1)^2/4-9)};
        \addplot[domain=-10:-3] {2-sqrt(9*(x+1)^2/4-9)};
        \addplot[domain=1:10] {2+sqrt(9*(x+1)^2/4-9)};
        \addplot[domain=1:10] {2-sqrt(9*(x+1)^2/4-9)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: first plot]

This is not a great plot (there's the obvious gap on the left, and if you look closer, you'll see that the right has a few straight segments and angles near the vertex).  To fix this, we can change to a parametric plot: `x=2*sec(t)-1, y=3*tan(t)+2`.  Plotting this still requires two commands (to avoid the vertical asymptotes of `sec` and `tan`) and results in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]
        \addplot[domain=-89:89] ({2*sec(x)-1},{3*tan(x)+2});
        \addplot[domain=91:269] ({2*sec(x)-1},{3*tan(x)+2});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: final plot]

Answer (score 2):

[image: text]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10, ymin=-15, ymax=15,
   restrict x to domain=-20:20]% remove crossing lines at t=90 and t=270
  \addplot[variable=t,domain=0:360,samples=200] ({2*sec(t)-1}, {3*tan(t)+2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]